# How to submit a form while woking with two toggle buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a form form which is holding Edit and save button.And it is also having enable and disabling text field functionality..

Example :

At first in form text fields will be disabled if user taps on "Edit" button then text field will be enable and user can edit the values.. And also user can see "Save" button instead of "Edit" button..
Once user taps on "Save" after editing the values.. then, text fields should be disable and "Edit" button should be placed instead of "Save".But still user should be on same screen.it is working fine. Now the problem is on saving the value. If use taps on "Save" button i want to save the form values in database. So i want to use **form tag** .. if i use **form tag** this function is not working. Can any one please help me..

Here is my code ..

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form Demo</title>
<script>
function disable() 
{
document.getElementById("Text1").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("Text2").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("Text3").disabled = true;   
}
function enable()
{
document.getElementById("Text1").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("Text2").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("Text3").disabled = false;
} 
function SwitchButtons(buttonId)
{
var hideBtn, showBtn, menuToggle;
if (buttonId == 'button1') 
{
menuToggle = 'menu2';
showBtn = 'button2';
hideBtn = 'button1';
} 
else 
{
menuToggle = 'menu3';
showBtn = 'button1';
hideBtn = 'button2';
}
document.getElementById(hideBtn).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(showBtn).style.display = ''; 

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
First Name: <input type="text" id="Text1" disabled  value="Mickey"><br>
Second Name: <input type="text" id="Text2" disabled value="Mouse"><br>
Address: <input type="text" id="Text3" disabled value="Hello World"><br>
<button  type="submit" onclick="disable(); SwitchButtons('button1');"       id="button1" class="sideviewtoggle myButton" style="display:none;">Save</button>
<button onclick="enable(); SwitchButtons('button2');" id="button2"      class="sideviewtoggle myButton" >Edit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[[[image: Disabled Text Fields with "Edit" button]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao5Q2.png) [[image: Enabled Text Fields with "Save" button]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykLFq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZJxA.png)

Comment: Use web services.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're not using jQuery or other library that would make this exercise far more simpler?

Comment: i am new to this.. So,i don't like to go in very complicated manner.. Also if i use any library it may affect some other functionality in my website.

Comment: You can include jQuery in a "no conflict" mode.  I think your current approach is more complicated and more error-prone for not using a library which abstracts you from specific DOM implementations.  e.g. you could disable all controls on the page with one line of code: $('input,select').prop('disabled', true);